What's the canonical way of sharing `TypedData` between Dart and C using FFI?
Let's say I have some raw data in a TypedData instance that I'd like to process using a C library through FFI. The result of this operation is another TypedData.
Concrete example: imagine we have a heatmap (as an array of doubles). This heatmap is dynamic, and changes as often as every frame. We want to construct a voronoi representation of the heatmap using vertices. Ideally, we'd get the final Float32List (positions) and the Int32List (colors) so we can use them directly in Vertices.raw. Moreover, those arrays shouldn't be instantiated every frame — they should be reused.
I'm not sure how to correctly do this using Dart FFI. Ideally, I would like to own the typed data in Dart:
// Init.
final heatmap = Float64List(500 * 500);
final outPositions = Float32List(maxVertices * 2);
final outColors = Int32List(maxVertices);

Now I'd like to call a C function using Dart FFI and provide both the input and the output by reference.
// Later...

ffiCall(heatmap, out);

// Now, use out...

There's .address, but that can only be used for a leaf native external call, and I'm not sure I should make the FFI function a leaf call.
There's also Struct. Struct makes it easy to provide arrays of a statically-known size, like this:
final class MyStruct extends Struct {
  @Array(100 * 100)
  external Array<Uint8> inlineArray;
}

But in many cases, the size of the array is only known at runtime.
Basically, I'd like to be able to construct a struct like the following one, in Dart, and then send it by reference to C code:
// A struct specifying some Dart data to be processed in C.
typedef struct
{
  int width;
  int height;
  double* data;
} my_struct;

Failing that, I'd like to minimize copying large data between Dart and C. I have found a similar question to this one but the author was happy with "several milliseconds" for the copy -- which is fine for a once-in-a-while operation, but not for something that might run every frame.
Is that possible? What's the canonical way of doing something like this?
